# How to POST/PUT on a Map<String,Entity> collection association

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Maybe a dumb question but how to update the content of a typed Map `collection association` of an exposed entity with `Spring Data Rest` using POST/PUT requests ?

I know how to POST/PUT on List or Set associations using `Content-Type: text/uri-list` but i don't with key/value Map<>

**EDIT**

I tried to send a ressource URI on the body of a PUT request with `Content-Type: text/uri-list` on the association endpoint. I gave no error, but it replaced all the previous content of the Map<> by this :

```
{ 
   self: { ENTITY content} 
}
```

So it seems to be supported (a side effect ?). It named the key `self`. 
I don't know how to specify the key.

Comment: Nothing because i don't know what to set on the HTTP body.

Comment: Is the relationship bi-directional and does the associated type have a repository exported as a Rest resource? If so the other approach is to post to the endpoint of the repository for the associated type.

Comment: My question is not specific to a use case but a "how to" do that in spring data rest. I tried with both associated entity Repository exported or not. The association was not bi-directionnal. I made a simple demo project in a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-960?jql=project%20%3D%20DATAREST) i post around this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebService
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {


    @GET
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HashMap<String, String> findAll() {

        HashMap<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
        test.put("key1", "value1");
        test.put("key2", "value2");
        return test;
    }
```

This produces JSON at the front end:

```
{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"}
```

However this does use application/json content type which may not be what you are after?

Comment: Sorry this does not answer my question. I use Spring Data Rest which exposes automatically my domain model Entity classes into rest resources. The GET resource works well but i don't know how to POST or PUT on a Map<> association.

Comment: look at the data you get from a get, then just post the same data back!

Comment: `Spring Data Rest` creates special sub-resources endpoints on entity associations which allows you to POST or PUT lists of resources URI on them (HATEOAS). This is the normal way to do things in `Spring Data Rest` to deal with associations. What i don't know is in the case where the association type is a Java Map. I need to specify the key but i don't know how, if it is possible and the normal way to do that.

Comment: So the issue is with the entity mapping rather than the type of content to send to the resource?

Comment: The issue is: how to POST/PUT requests on an [association resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) when the association is mapped with a @*-ToMany Map<String, Entity>